# Ruby on Rails 4.2.0 with rspec-rails 3.1.0 and shoulda-matchers 2.7.0 undefined method `validates_presence_of' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda

i'm using **Ruby on Rails 4.2.0** with **rspec-rails 3.1.0** and **shoulda-matchers 2.7.0**

when run test i have this error

```
Failure/Error: it { should validates_presence_of :name }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `validates_presence_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Profile::Vaidations:0x00000007881768>
     # ./spec/models/profile_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

this is my model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :phone, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :age, presence: true, length: {maximum: 4}
end
```

and this is my spec file

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe Profile do
  describe "vaidations" do
    it { should validates_presence_of :name }

    it { should validates_presence_of :age }
    it { should validates_numericality_of :age }

    it { should validates_presence_of :phone }
    it { should validates_uniqueness_of :phone }

    it { should validates_presence_of :username }
    it { should validates_uniqueness_of :username }
  end

  describe 'association' do
    it { should belongs_to :user }
  end
end
```

and this is my test group in my gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

i find the same error on shoulda-matchers [repo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/203) but with different versions and it didn't work for me!!
what can i do?!!

Comment: have you tried this `it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }` ?

Comment: Try adding: `describe Profile, type: :model do`

Comment: @AdhamEl-Deeb what error you are getting for other fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please replace following code.

```
it { should validates_presence_of :name }
```

with

```
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: and it works with **it { validate_presence_of(:name) }** without **is_expected.to** the problem was the "s" in **validates** it is **validate** only with out the "s"

Comment: `it { validate_presence_of(:name) }` doesn't do anything: it instantiates the `validate_presence_of` matcher but doesn't use it in an expectation, so the example will pass, but it will never be able to fail, either.

Answer (score 2):

```
.....
 it { should validate_presence_of :name }
.....
```

You must delete character 'S' from 'validateS_presence_of' in all strings

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it **it { should validates_presence_of :name }**
write **it { should validate_presence_of :name }**